# Holder JS will not work with %

Tags: holder.js

I am using the latest version of holder.js from [here](https://github.com/imsky/holder)

How ever if I try to use percentage for the width like

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100%x380" class="img-responsive">
```

Does not work. In older version it did but not in current versions

**Question** How can I make holder.js use % for width in latest versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how to get full width with latest version of holder js

Instead of `%` use `px` like

100 for full width and then you can have any height your after.

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100px380" class="img-responsive">
```

[Link](https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/190#event-702365721)